# ¿Se pueden crear atajos o snippets para ayudar con la redacción de preguntas y respuestas en el sitio?

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad, ediciones

Es posible que esta pregunta vaya en [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) más que aquí, pero de momento allá va.

Tras un tiempo aquí me encuentro con que hay dos formatos de texto que suelo usar mucho. El primero es la definición, que suelo formatear así:

> **palabra (con enlace)**
>
> Etimología
>
> 1. Significado 1.
> 2. Significado 2.

El segundo es la cita textual de libros, que suelo formatear así:

> *Texto citado.*
>
> Autor, "Título", año (País)

La cuestión es, ¿existe la posibilidad de crear pequeños snippets para facilitar estas tareas? Estos snippets podrían ser específicos de cada sitio que los necesite. Así, con estos ejemplos podríamos tener algo así:

```
[def[palabra[enlace]][etimología][definiciones]]
[cita[Texto citado][Autor][Título][Año][País]]
```

Así, bastaría con insertar estos snippets para facilitar la tarea de insertar determinados bloques en las preguntas y respuestas.

¿Se ha contemplado esta opción en los sitios?

Comment: Sería fantástico tener algo así. Se me antoja complicado que se implemente nativamente por parte de los devs de [se], pero sí veo plausible conseguirlo en forma de Stack App: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @fedorqui ¿una Stack App sería como lo de las "stinking badges" que me enlazaste el otro día? Pero entonces no estaría integrado con el editor de preguntas y respuestas de Stack Exchange, que sería lo que molaría. Habría que hacer un editor aparte en forma de aplicación, o una App que dado el snippet te devolviera el código a insertar en el editor.

Comment: No he explorado esa página en exceso (corregí el enlace de mi anterior comentario, por cierto), pero por lo que he visto engloba tanto APIs como pequeños plugins y add-ons para incorporar al navegador. Por ejemplo hay alguno que utiliza la API de SE para desglosar los puntos positivos y negativos a aquellos que aún no tienen privilegios para verlos. En el caso que planteas en tu pregunta, yo pensaba en algún tipo de add-on que se incorporara al editor automáticamente y autocompletara según los parámetros dados.

Comment: @fedorqui pues no estaría mal, incluso se podría hacer uno que, dada una palabra, la buscara en la web de la RAE y transformara el código HTML proporcionado por _markup_ de Stack Exchange. Así sería incluso más fácil.

Comment: Investiguemos :) De hecho, veo que hay una API no oficial para el DRAE: [Raequel](http://raequel.sebastianoliva.com/).

Answer (score 2):

En Chess.SE tienen algo similar para incorporar tableros de ajedrez interactivos en las preguntas y respuestas. Y son un stack Beta igual que nosotros.

Por ejemplo, en https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/19926/is-castling-legal-in-this-position, si editas la pregunta verás que el código para la tabla mostrada es este:

```
 [title "-"]
 [fen "r3k2r/pp1nnp2/2pB2pp/3p1p2/3P4/2N3PB/PPP1PP1P/R3K2R b KQkq - 0 1"]
```

La petición para implementar tal maravilla se inició [en este post de Chess.Meta](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-implement-a-replayer-for-chess-analysis-on-the-site), y parece que la manera de conseguirlo fue incluyendo un plugin de jQuery en el código del sitio principal. Ahora bien, el cómo incluir un script así en nuestro stack, se me escapa. ¿Quizá colando el script como parte del HTML del banner? :D

En cualquier caso, nótese que esto fue **desarrollado e implementado por usuarios del stack**. Los devs de SE no tuvieron nada que ver, o al menos no lo parece.

Lo cierto es que yo también estoy bastante interesado en disponer de algo así. Si lo veis viable, podemos intentar desarrollarlo nosotros mismos.